# Good Lich Resources

Tags: dnd-4e, campaign-development

I'm trying to develop a plot were a cult leader is trying to become a lich.  Do any of the currently published D&D 4e books provide any canon for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Open Grave*](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105221807/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/9780786950690) is your best reference. It doesn't contain any mechanics related to becoming a lich, but the first chapter includes a section on how undead are created. It's also got rules for grafting undead parts onto yourself, which might prove useful.

[*Revenge of the Giants*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915174650/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/241787400) features the legendary lich Acererak before he became a lich. You can gain some insight into the process there, although it's not worth buying the book just for that one bit.

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* includes a lich template on page 179. You'd probably want to apply this template to the cult leader if his or her plans succeeded.

Comment: Open Grave fits the bill, and I read the section from Revenge of the Giants at the book store. (Sorry BAMM, I do by from you a lot though.) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [Lich Transformation Ritual](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=71) from the WotC compendium.

Answer (score 1):

*Open Grave* and the recently adapted *Tomb of Horrors*. There are a lot of story hooks dealing with undead and lichdom in both of them, and *Tomb of Horrors* in particular deals with the system's most famous demilich of all time.

Answer (score 1):

In D&D second edition, Enciclopaedia Magica has all the rules for the ritual to *lichification*. I guess also [Van Richten's guide to the Lich](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560765720) might come in handy, if not for the rules, at least for fluff :)